# how to validate website address using angular 5

Tags: angular, url-validation

I would like to validate url in angular 5 not working.

```html
<input type="url" name="url" id="url" ngModel pattern="https?://.+">
<div *ngIf="url.errors && (url.dirty || url.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">

  <div [hidden]="!url.errors.pattern">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To Validate the URL / Web address in a reactive form you can follow the below method, using `Validators.pattern` against the form control.

```
const urlRegex = '(https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})[/\\w .-]*/?';

 this.hospitalForm = this.fb.group({
   Website: ['', Validators.pattern(urlRegex)],
 });
```

To validate the URL / Web Address in a template driven form, you should create a custom Validator directive as follows

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appPattern]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: PatternValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class PatternValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appPattern') pattern: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    return this.pattern ? this.patternValidator(new RegExp(this.pattern, 'i'))(control)
                              : null;
  }

 patternValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
   return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
           const regextest = nameRe.test(control.value);
           return (!regextest) ? {'apppattern': {value: control.value}} : null;
   };
  }
}
```

In your input, you should use appUrl with the regex, :

```
<input  type="url" name="url" id="url" ngModel appPattern="(https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})[/\\w .-]*/?">
```

Comment: thanks for reponse. I am using template driven approach. 

not sure what   Website: ['', Validators.pattern(urlRegex)], code is doing

Comment: Hi ,I have done below

<label for="url" class="control-label">URL</label>
  <input  (blur)="update(false)" required pattern="^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$"
         id="url" type="text" class="form-control" name="url"
         [(ngModel)]="urls" #url="ngModel">
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="url.errors?.required && url.touched">
    URL is required
  </span>
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="url.errors?.pattern && url.touched">
    URL is Invalid
  </span>

One issue is onblur get called when url.errors how to check on .ts file

Comment: what you mean by that issue? can you explain it a bit

Comment: I have tried you solution but patternValidator in not define please help

Comment: have you added it in your module declarations?

Comment: updated my answer pls check it. i have created patternvalidator method inside the directive